# Why is this Overflow Occuring?

Tags: c

In the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_authentication(char *password) {  
    char password_buffer[16];   
    int auth_flag = 0;

    strcpy(password_buffer, password);

    if(strcmp(password_buffer, "brillig") == 0)
        auth_flag = 1;
    if(strcmp(password_buffer, "outgrabe") == 0)
    auth_flag = 1;

    return auth_flag;
}

int  main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc < 2){
         printf("Usage: %s <password>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);    
    }

        if(check_authentication(argv[1])){
        printf("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-\n");
        printf("  Access Granted\n");
        printf("-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Access Denied\n");
    }       
}
```

if I run something such as "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", somehow something is overflowed and it causes the program to run as access granted. I'm confused because when I ran the gdb debugger, auth_flag was before password_buffer in the memory and it was never overflowed.

**EDIT**: I understand that the text doesn't fit into the buffer but I am experimenting with buffer overflows and how to exploit them in a controlled manner. Yes, we could make the array bigger but that's not the point of this

I was wondering if someone would be able to tell me why this is happening/what is being overflowed to cause this.

Comment: When you size the buffer, it need to be length+1 as it need the terminating null character.

Comment: As already explained, you are invoking Undefined Behaviour. So there can be no standard answer. Any answer is dependent on the system, the compiler and the compile options used. So if you really want a decent answer you need to provide that information.

Answer (score 5):

**AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA** has size 20. You are then using `strcpy` to copy it to an char array of size 16. Try increasing your password_buffer size.

> To avoid overflows, the size of the array pointed by destination
>   shall be long enough to contain the same C string as source (including
>   the terminating null character), and should not overlap in memory with
>   source.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

Comment: but what I am confused about still is that the reason why access granted occurs is if auth_flag is not zero. if we use this string, I understand it overflows the buffet, but why would it cause access granted? (auth_flag >0)

Comment: @yasgur99 overflowing a buffer causes Undefined Behaviour. In that case anything can happen.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are copying the input into a buffer that is too small (and for no reason). Your method could be implemented (without overflow) like

```
int check_authentication(const char *password) {
    size_t len = strlen(password);

    return strncmp(password, "brillig", len) == 0 ||
           strncmp(password, "outgrabe", len) == 0;
}
```

> I understand it overflows the buffet, but why would it cause access granted? (auth_flag >0)

Because `auth_flag` is the next `int` in memory after `char password_buffer[16];`. With some compilers (and operating systems), if you overflow `password_buffer`, there is a high probability that you modify `auth_flag`.

Comment: I'm not trying to get the code to work correctly, I understand it is overflowing and that's why there is an issue, but I can't seem to find out what's causing this to happen specifically

Comment: @yasgur99 Edited. In your code, the `int` for `auth_flag` is almost certainly **stored** immediately after `password_buffer` (in memory).

Comment: I checked in the debugger and it isn't. I don't know if that has to do with being on Linux/Little Endian but I'm 1000% sure that password_buffer is after auth_flag

Comment: @yasgur99 Have you examined the output of `gcc -S`? Also, I'm just trying to help ... if you've examined it with `gdb` (or some other debugger) at run-time, you should add the complete run-time trace to your question. And improve your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

The memory is stored in the stack in a consecutive manner, 
so there's a char[16] and an int that indicates whether the authentication passed successfully.

When you pass in a pointer to a buffer and copies it without boundary checking the local buffer, you risking overflowing your buffer and rewriting your stack variables.

When you input 'A' * 20, the first 16 'A' went into the buffer, and the remaining 4 'A's went into the int (usually sizeof(int) is 4 bytes).

So now, your int is not 0, it's:
auth = 0x41414141 
since the ASCII code of 'A' is 0x41.

There's a really great article related to this - 
http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html

It lays out the basics of stack overflows and gets a little more advanced later on.